# D3 force directed navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, navigation, force-layout

I need advice from experienced web designers. I've had this idea of making a more original navigation menu in particular an interactive graph where the nodes are the buttons which expand onclick to create the submenu graph and add content to the page or redirect to another page.

Visually the way that I want the menu to look and behave is very close to some examples of the D3.js library

[Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941)

[Foci Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841)

The problem is that since the D3 library is for data representation, I am not sure If it is convenient and right to use it for navigation menu. I've tried to search for websites with such design but I didn't find anything which makes me think that this is really not the right approach. So in one word my questions are:

What is the right approach to implement this idea?

Have you seen any websites with similar design?

Comment: If you can represent your menu as a tree _"data"_, then there is no reason you cannot use D3 for it. As for an example, is this sort of menu you have in mind: http://www.consumerbarometer.com/#?app=explore